# Storing activities in an array

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing a quiz app in which when the user presses the next button , he gets to a different activity that is the next question . Also it will have a previous button which takes to the previous question . So what I am thinking is to store all the activities in an array(if thats possible) . Later when I need to add or remove the question from the app then I will only have to change the array and delete its activity file .

Comment: if you change the activity that means you will have a new button next and a new onClickListner for it so why you don't just implement onClick for each next Button of all activities !!

Comment: Its a very bad idea ...

Comment: worst idea, EVER. You only need one activity and a list of questions/answers. if you have a quiz app with 100 questions, thats 100 activities. worst possible thing for an android app, or any app. i advice you to think this.

Comment: I want the screen to change when the user presses the next or previous button . For that I would need a new activity . Also this is a practice project so I am learning things and I want to do it in this way !

Comment: if you want to practice then you should REALLY practice doing it the right way not your way. If you want there to be a "new screen" when a user clicks on 'next', then all you need to do is UPDATE the current activity with a new question from your list. you will never get the answer that you want here.

Answer (score 1):

That is a really bad idea. Instead,  in the activity where the user chooses the question activity, pass data through the intent and deal with the logic in the receiver activity itself. Like so:

```
 Intent j = new Intent (this, 
 QuestionsActivity.class/*whatever your activity's name 
 is */);
 j.putExtra("questionNumber",13/*Arbitrary number*/);
 startActivity(j);
```

Then in the activity....
     if (getIntent().getIntExtra("questionNumber") == 13) 
       //Do what you want here

Answer (score 0):

You should never, ever maintain references to multiple Activities. The Android system may decide at any time to destroy an Activity and your references will no longer be valid.

Instead you should separate the model of questions from the way they are displayed in an Activity. You can send data to an activity, for example some identifier for the question or even the text of the question. Your Activity subclass should be general-purpose in that it can display any question. This allows you to create **one** activity for all questions rather than one activity for each question.

You can keep an array of questions rather than activities and then use that array to display the correct information as needed.